# no error when submit as a form but an error as a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a form in which there are two buttons.

one of them is the submit button which checks all the fields in the form and there is a username field which is not only checked by the submit button of the form, but also it is checked with a separate check button.

in the username field I have to come up with a pattern that has the following characteristics:

1.username must be between 8 to 12 characters

2.username must be comprised of numbers,letters(uppercase or lowercase),dot,dash,underline

3.username must start with letters.

check button works based on a JavaScript function that I have written myself.

the problem is:

when I enter "s_123asd" as a username, submit button doesn't give me any error but when I check it with check button, I get pattern mismatch error.

clearly there is a problem with my function because the pattern works just fine in regex101.

please help

thanks in advance

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function pattern() {
    var x = document.forms["regForm"]["uname"].value;
    if (x.pattern != "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{7,11}") {
        alert("pattern mismatch");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="regForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

username: <input type="text" name="uname" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{7,11}" id="uname">
<button type="button" onclick="pattern()">check</button><br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is working fine for me! When i enter the username you provided it is giving an error!

Comment: In your own `pattern()` function you don't run a regex, you simply compare 2 strings

Comment: I also noticed you haven't accepted, and barely upvoted, any of the answers to your question. Aren't you aware you are suppose to?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `test()`. The `test()` method tests for a match in the string specified in the parameter.
This method returns true if it finds a match, otherwise returns false.

Try the following way:

```js
function pattern() {
  var x = document.forms["regForm"]["uname"].value;
  var patt = /[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{7,11}/;
  if (!patt.test(x)) { // notice the use of ! to negate the test result
    alert("pattern mismatch");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="regForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

username: <input type="text" name="uname" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]{7,11}" id="uname">
<button type="button" onclick="pattern()">check</button><br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

It's because in your HTML you forgot to rename function to call in onsubmit from validateForm() to pattern(). It worked when i change it from

```
onsubmit="return validateForm()"
```

to

```
onsubmit="return pattern()"
```

Check https://jsfiddle.net/gwf0u6er/